# Why is not the prepared div added?

Tags: javascript

It's work https://jsfiddle.net/w0m89w3e/1/

This doesn't work https://jsfiddle.net/op488m49/1/

HTML

```
<div id="add">add block</div>
<div id="new_b"></div>
```

JS 1

```
var div = '';
add.onclick = function() {
    var div = document.createElement('div');
    div.className = "alert";
    div.id = "vv";
    div.innerHTML = "<strong>Yes!</strong> ";
    new_b.appendChild(div);
};
```

JS2

```
add.onclick = function() {
    var div = '<div id="a"><p class="my">text</p></div>'
    new_b.appendChild(div);
};
```

Error:

> Uncaught ReferenceError: new_b is not defined at
>   HTMLDivElement.add.onclick

What should I do if I need to load a complex DIV into the new block with several nested levels?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var div = '';
add.onclick = function() {
    var div = document.createElement('div');
    div.className = "alert";
    div.id = "vv";
    div.innerHTML = "<div id='complex-div'><strong>Yes!</strong></div>";
    new_b.appendChild(div);
};
```

Answer (score 1):

```
add.onclick = function() {
    var div = '<div id="a"><p class="my">text</p></div>'
    new_b.appendChild(div);
};
```

In this case variable  `div`  is just a string. You need a DOM element to use in appendChild. In first case `div` is element

You can use `insertAdjacentHTML` for complex div

https://jsfiddle.net/op488m49/2/

```
add.onclick = function() {
    var div = '<div id="a"><p class="my">text</p></div>'
    new_b.insertAdjacentHTML( 'beforeend', div );
};
```

Answer (score 0):

You are not creating the DIV. You need to create it (or any element) before append it.
What do you mean with "complex DIV"? Can you show an example?